# Typescript definitions from postgresql query result

Tags: json, postgresql, typescript

Suppose you have a complex query returning hierarchical JSON. How to generate Typescript definitions of the query result?

Comment: Please add an example of the complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Like Martin Vseticka wrote, the actual JSON you're getting would help. Here's a semi-complex example I had to work with:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyPjT.png

The strategy I follow is to identify the lowest level bits of any tier and then assemble them one by one under a parent until you get to the root.

The TS interface to describe it (with a few comments) is this:

```html
module RL.SS.Portal.RLToday.Interfaces {

    // Don't blame us for this craziness. This is the zoo that MMS ASMX service unleashes when it succeeds.
    /*
        data
            TermStore
                T: [] of
                    DS: string or object, --> this is where the description would go if there is one. blank string if no desciption, otherwise object ->
                        TD: object ->
                            a11: string (the description;  you can see and edit this description in the UI)
                    LS: object ->
                        TL: object -> **NOTE: this will be an array if there are multiple labels.
                            a31: boolean (seems to be if it's the default value when there are multiple labels)
                            a32: string (seems to be the value of the term as a string)
                    TMS: object ->
                        TM: object ->
                            a12: "Locations" (prob term set name)
                            a17: boolean (seems to indicate whether end users can use this for tagging. visible in the term set UI via site collection admin)
                            a24: string (guid, parent ID if any)
                            a40: string, blank in the sample I have
                            a45: string (guid, not sure what)
                            a67: string, blank in my sample
                    a9: guid of the term
                    a21: boolean, true if there are children
                    a61: "0" in my sample

      This is very hard to model since they vary on whether something is an array or not based on the alternative keywords.

      This definition assumes for now that there are not variable keywords.

      None of the GUIDs have parenthesis in the raw result.
    */
    export interface MmsAsmxTL {
        _a31: boolean, // Indicates if it's the default term label (mainly useful if there are multiple labels for this term)
        _a32: string // Value of the term
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxLS {
        TL: MmsAsmxTL
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxTM {
        _a12: string, // name of the term set
        _a17: boolean, // whether it's available for tagging or not
        _a24: string, // some kind of guid,
        _a40: string, // Not sure,
        _a45: string, // guid, not sure for what,
        _a67: string // another blank string as per the sample data
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxTMS {
        TM: MmsAsmxTM;
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxTD {
        _a11: string; // Description of the term. Not mandatory.
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxDS {
        TD ?: MmsAsmxTD // optional, will not exist if there's not description
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxT {
        DS: MmsAsmxDS,
        LS: MmsAsmxLS,
        TMS: MmsAsmxTMS,
        _a9: string, // guid of the term
        _a21: boolean, // whether there are children
        _a61: string
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxTermStore {
        T: MmsAsmxT[]
    }

    export interface MmsAsmxData {
        TermStore: MmsAsmxTermStore;
    }
    export interface MmsAsmxSuccessResult {
        data: MmsAsmxData;
    }
}
```

HTH.